# Spring Boot: Repository and Entity beans not recognized error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

My code doesn't seem to recognize some of my repositories and entity classes. I have two databases, LoadMethod and MTS, that I am dealing with. I have had this error for about two days and everything I've found online has mentioned bad package names or missing annotations, but I seem to have all of that to my knowledge.

This is my project package structure:

[image]

This is my console output:

```
2016-08-16 09:03:13.310  INFO 4724 --- [           main] database.Application                     : Starting Application on LR90KLWJY with PID 4724 (C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method\bin started by vincni in C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method)
2016-08-16 09:03:13.313  INFO 4724 --- [           main] database.Application                     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-16 09:03:13.357  INFO 4724 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15bfd87: startup date [Tue Aug 16 09:03:13 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-16 09:03:14.080  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'TBL_GroupRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
2016-08-16 09:03:14.652  INFO 4724 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'lmPersistenceUnit'
2016-08-16 09:03:14.679  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: lmPersistenceUnit
    ...]
2016-08-16 09:03:14.757  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-08-16 09:03:14.758  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-16 09:03:14.760  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-16 09:03:14.960  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-08-16 09:03:15.715  WARN 4724 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.d.i.StandardDialectResolver      : HHH000385: Unknown Microsoft SQL Server major version [12] using SQL Server 2000 dialect
2016-08-16 09:03:15.720  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
2016-08-16 09:03:15.851  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-16 09:03:16.062  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-08-16 09:03:16.062  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-08-16 09:03:16.063  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-08-16 09:03:16.090  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: dbMOBClientTemp.dbo.Client
2016-08-16 09:03:16.090  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [expndedidind, isd_lupd_ts, client_id, isd_lupd_id]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.090  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
2016-08-16 09:03:16.090  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [pxclient]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.101  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: dbMOBClientTemp.dbo.LoadMethod
2016-08-16 09:03:16.101  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [actind, loadmthdcd, dtltransrcdind, media_id, acctmngdind, formatmapcd, isd_lupd_ts, isd_lupd_id]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.101  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
2016-08-16 09:03:16.101  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [pxldmthd]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.110  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: dbMOBClientTemp.dbo.LoadMethodClient
2016-08-16 09:03:16.110  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [media_id, isd_lupd_ts, client_id, isd_lupd_id]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.110  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: [rcmedialm, rcclientlm]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.110  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [pxlmc]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.117  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: dbMOBClientTemp.dbo.LoadMethodComments
2016-08-16 09:03:16.117  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [ec_sk, media_id, cmt, isd_lupd_ts, isd_lupd_id]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.118  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: [rcmediaid]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.118  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [pxlmcmt]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.118  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
2016-08-16 09:03:16.163  INFO 4724 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'mtsPersistentUnit'
2016-08-16 09:03:16.163  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: mtsPersistentUnit
    ...]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.382  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
2016-08-16 09:03:16.386  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-16 09:03:16.392  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-08-16 09:03:16.392  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-08-16 09:03:16.392  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-08-16 09:03:16.418  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: dbMTS.dbo.tblGROUP
2016-08-16 09:03:16.418  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [date_updated, penalty_ind, media_count, y2k_advised, download_full, label_spec, who_entered, group_inactive, report_preference, edi_type, prod_test_ind, late_status, frequency, g_tech_num, media_type, control_number, hot_loadt, media_id, date_entered, id, mit_id, emc_synch_flag, who_updated, block_size, strategic_group, report_processor, format_program, gmisc_flag_2, gmisc_flag_1, gmisc_flag_3, record_size, four_digit_year, respon_anal, time_updated, open_enroll_mnth, use_tpa_contact, ol_id, fk_tpa_id, zeke_event, name, time_entered, package_name, group_maint_ind, elig_password, edt_advised, need_labels, spanned_zipfile]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.418  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: [rcgrpadmin]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.418  INFO 4724 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [pxgroup]
2016-08-16 09:03:16.419  INFO 4724 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
2016-08-16 09:03:16.628  WARN 4724 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TBL_GroupRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class database.mts.dataobjects.TBL_GroupDO
2016-08-16 09:03:16.630  INFO 4724 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'mtsPersistentUnit'
2016-08-16 09:03:16.630  INFO 4724 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'lmPersistenceUnit'
2016-08-16 09:03:16.636 ERROR 4724 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TBL_GroupRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class database.mts.dataobjects.TBL_GroupDO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at database.Application.main(Application.java:30) [bin/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class database.mts.dataobjects.TBL_GroupDO
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:152) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:99) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted

2016-08-16 09:03:16.639  INFO 4724 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/vincni/git/consumer_load_method/bin/, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-ftp/jars/camel-ftp-2.16.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-core/bundles/camel-core-2.16.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/jars/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/jars/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.jcraft/jsch/jars/jsch-0.1.53.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/commons-net/commons-net/jars/commons-net-3.3.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/jars/HikariCP-2.4.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/jars/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/jars/spring-boot-starter-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/jars/spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-core/jars/spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-context/jars/spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-aop/jars/spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-beans/jars/spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-expression/jars/spring-expression-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/jars/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/jars/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/jars/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/jars/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.yaml/snakeyaml/bundles/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/jars/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/jars/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/jars/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli/jars/tomcat-juli-8.0.36.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/jars/spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-tx/jars/spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/jars/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/jars/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/jars/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/jars/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/dom4j/dom4j/jars/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/jars/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/jars/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.javassist/javassist/bundles/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/antlr/antlr/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss/jandex/jars/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/jars/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/jars/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/jars/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-orm/jars/spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-aspects/jars/spring-aspects-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-jpa/jars/camel-jpa-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-spring/bundles/camel-spring-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi/jars/poi-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.5.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/jars/poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/jars/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/jars/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/jars/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar, file:/C:/ExternalJARS/ojdbc7.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/eclipselink.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpars_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/com.sun.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201004141950.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.activation_1.1.0.v201108011116.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200.jar]
```

This is my config file:

```
 package database.mts;

//all my imports//

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "mtsEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mtsTransactionManager")
public class MTS_Config {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mtsDatasource")
    public DataSource mtsDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mtsEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(mtsDataSource())
                .packages("database.mts.dataobjects")
                .persistenceUnit("mtsPersistentUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    PlatformTransactionManager mtsTransactionManager( @Qualifier("mtsEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

This is my other config file:

```
package database.loadmethod;
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class LM_Config {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource lmDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lmEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(lmDataSource())
                .packages("database.loadmethod.dataobjects")
                .persistenceUnit("lmPersistenceUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager lmTransactionManager( @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

This is my entity object of interest (the one that doesnt seem to be recognized):

```
package database.mts.dataobjects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tblGROUP")
public class TBL_GroupDO {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private String id;
    @Column(name="MEDIA_ID")
    private String mediaId;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMediaId() {
        return mediaId;
    }
    public void setMediaId(String mediaId) {
        this.mediaId = mediaId;
    }
}
```

This is the repository of interest:

```
package database.mts.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import database.mts.dataobjects.TBL_GroupDO;

public interface TBL_GroupRepository extends CrudRepository<TBL_GroupDO, String>{

}
```

This is my application file:

```
package database;
//imports//

@SpringBootApplication//(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories //(basePackages = {"database.loadmethod.repositories", "database.mts.repositories"})
//@EntityScan(basePackages = {"database.loadmethod.dataobjects", "database.mts.dataobjects"})
//@EntityScan
//@EnableTransactionManagement

public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(LoadMethodRepository lm_repo, TBL_GroupRepository tblg_repo /*, LMClientRepository lmc_repo */) {
        return (args) -> {

            System.out.println("*********Media ID**************");
            System.out.println(lm_repo.findOne("4948460").getMediaId());
            System.out.println("*********Media ID**************");
            System.out.println(tblg_repo.findOne("8").getMediaId());
            System.out.println("*********Media ID**************");
        };
    }
}
```

This is my properties file:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx:1433;database=xxx;integratedSecurity=false;
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
#spring.jpa.database=xxx
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

spring.mtsDatasource.username=xxx
spring.mtsDatasource.password=xxxxx
spring.mtsDatasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://VSQLCON2:1433;database=dbMTS;integratedSecurity=false;
spring.mtsDatasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.mtsDatasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.mtsDatasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver


hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.default_schema=dbo
hibernate.packagesToScan=src.repositories.LMClientRepository.java
```

Comment: Are you potentially overriding your `@Entity` annotations with `hibernate.packagesToScan=src.repositories.LMClientRepository.java`

Comment: Remove `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your main class. Also sharing so much code here is a bit of a wasted time. You could rather share a sample that we could actually run and I am sure you'll get an answer much faster by doing so.

Comment: Please create a minimal working example.

Comment: Stephane that worked thank you. I'll keep that in mind